# Iterate through tuple nested in a list and select top 1 for each tuple group based on date

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

relatively new to Python, not new to programming. There are system constraints in place for me where I cannot perform this operation via SQL - I need to do all of this via Python 3.x.

I need to get a subset of the Sample data below grouped by FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 and sorted by FIELD5(date) ASC.

**Sample data:**

```
    [['FIELD1', 'FIELD2', 'FIELD3', 'FIELD4', 'FIELD5'], 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'BICYCLE', 'RED', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 17, 47, 300172)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'BICYCLE', 'RED', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'BICYCLE', 'RED', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 40, 49, 756362)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'MOTORCYCLE', 'GREEN', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'MOTORCYCLE', 'GREEN', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 40, 49, 756362)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'MOTORCYCLE', 'GREEN', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 17, 47, 300172)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'PLAID', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 40, 49, 756362)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'PINK', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 17, 47, 300172)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'BLUE', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'PURPLE', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 2, 23, 16, 395861)), ...
```

**Result set:**

```
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'BICYCLE', 'RED', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'MOTORCYCLE', 'GREEN', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'PURPLE', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 2, 23, 16, 395861)),...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is already sorted into groups, we can use `groupby` to isolate those groups, then run `max` over them to get entry with the largest date:

```
import datetime
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

l = [(9220123, '18002744100', 'BICYCLE', 'RED', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 17, 47, 300172)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'BICYCLE', 'RED', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'BICYCLE', 'RED', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 40, 49, 756362)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'MOTORCYCLE', 'GREEN', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'MOTORCYCLE', 'GREEN', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 40, 49, 756362)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'MOTORCYCLE', 'GREEN', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 17, 47, 300172)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'PLAID', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 40, 49, 756362)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'PINK', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 23, 17, 47, 300172)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'BLUE', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
    (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'PURPLE', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 2, 23, 16, 395861))]

groups = map(itemgetter(1), groupby(l, key=itemgetter(0, 1, 2)))
maxes = [max(g, key=itemgetter(4)) for g in groups]
print(maxes)
```

prints

```
[(9220123, '18002744100', 'BICYCLE', 'RED', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
 (9220123, '18002744100', 'MOTORCYCLE', 'GREEN', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 14, 49, 342347)), 
 (9220123, '18002744100', 'UNICYCLE', 'PURPLE', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 2, 23, 16, 395861))]
```